# Why does the updating to database through JPA roll back?

Tags: java, jpa, rollback

I'm using spring boot starter jpa 2.1.8.

Here's what I did. In a http request handler method annotated with **@Transactional(RollbaclFor = Exception.class)**, I queried some object through jpaRepository and modified some property of that object. But I **didn't** call the repository.save() method. After the request is finished, I checked the database and my modification succeeded. But later, when a scheduled thread queried the same object through jpa, my previous modification disappeared!

I wonder why is this happening. The updating was difinitely written to the database, but was rolled back later.

I tried to save the updating by calling **repository.save()** method, and **it worked fine**. But I still want to know why is the updating written and rolled back when I didn't save the entity?

Can someone help me find out why?

Comment: read https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate: "When the entity instance is in the persistent state, all changes that you make to the mapped fields of this instance will be applied to the corresponding database records and fields upon flushing the Session. "

Comment: @NathanHughes But why can't another thread perceive that updating? When another thread retrieve the object, the property looked unchanged, as if the updating was rolled back.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you inadvertently saved the old values again?

Comment: think you should crank up log level for transactions and persistence so you have a chance of seeing what is really going on.